# 403 Status (Forbidden) when PUT and DELETE using AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, jax-rs

I've implemented a small REST API using JAX-RS (Jersey 2.0) and I'm using AJAX to call the API, GET and POST work fine but when I get to call any PUT or DELETE methods, all I get is the following error message:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)**

Here's an example of a **DELETE** method in Java:

```
    @Path("/deleteSomething")
    @DELETE
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void delete(String json) throws ParseException {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse( json );
        JSONObject object=(JSONObject)obj;

        String id = (String) object.get("id");
        System.out.println("ID  :   " + id);
        //DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
```

And here is the Javascript call using AJAX:

```
function deleteSomethingAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: API_URI + "/deleteSomething", //API_URI is the API's uri
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data: idToJSON(), // this function just returns a JSON obj {"id":"myID"}
        type:  'DELETE',
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert( "Fine!" );
        },

        error : function(jqXHR, data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('WOOPS, something wrent wrong...');
        }
    });
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!! Thank you!!

Comment: Instead of editing the question to include your solution, it would be better to simply post an answer (and "accept it").

Comment: @PaulRichter thank you for the suggestion, that's what I've just done.

Comment: @AntP thank you for the advice! I just posted the solution below and accepted it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue had to do with the CORSFilter set-up, I was setting it wrong in the **web.xml** file. Here is the part of the CORSFilter, well set inside **web.xml**:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```