# 403 when trying to delete by id (AngularJS + Spring)

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am new in AngularJS + Spring. I am trying to delete the current user by his ID. I have the following codes

user.controller.js

```
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        angular.module('app').controller('UserController', function($state, $location, $stateParams, User, user) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.user = null;
            vm.success = null;
            vm.userURL = $location.path();

            vm.deleteUser = function() {

                vm.user.$delete({id :  vm.user.id}, function(response) {
                    if (user.id == response.id) {
                        angular.extend(user, response);
                    }
                    vm.success = true;
                }, function() {
                    vm.success = false;
                });
            };

    })();
```

user.html

```
<md-button aria-label="DeleteUser" ng-click="uc.deleteUser()"> <md-icon md-menu-origin>clear</md-icon>Delete
    User</md-button>
```

and UserController.java

```
@RestController
@ExposesResourceFor(User.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UserController {

    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @Inject
    private UserResourceAssembler userResourceAssembler;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable final Long id) {
        userRepository.delete(id);
    }

}
```

If I press the delete button I get
DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/user/100 403 (Forbidden)
I have to mention that put, get, post are working and when I access http://localhost:3000/api/user/100, I get the right response.

Does anyone has a suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: Is any other delete api working?

Comment: it is the only place I have a delete operation. I imagined it was similar to $update which works well :-?

Comment: have you tried to call the delete URL directly via curl or some other client?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with your config for **web.xml**

For more info go to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193029/403-status-forbidden-when-put-and-delete-using-ajax)