# http get and post are OK but put and delete give error 403 on live server

Tags: angularjs, http, server, localhost

It drives me crazy, don't know where to look for a solution.

What's the situation?
I've made an angular app with a simple CRUD which works as it should on my localhost. 
Now i've migrated the app to a live server and it seemed if everything worked. I get the whole list of items in my table and I can add items to it. Great. 
But unfortunately the $http.delete and $http.put operations don't. They end up in a 403 error. Many people gave the advise to check the permissions. But I think they are set right: folders have 755 and inside those folders all files are set to 644.

What surprises me is that there is apparently a difference between the behavior of the app on localhost and on a live server. Why is that?

Is there anybody out there who can lead me to a solution of this mindbreaking frustration?

Joseph

Comment: Check your developer tools in browser and see for the errors in console and network tab, i really don't think its the permission issue, morelikely server configuration

Comment: what server side language are you using? maybe it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193029/403-status-forbidden-when-put-and-delete-using-ajax

Comment: Hm, are you using CORS? If yes, it's possible that PUT and DELETE method are not approved on api side?

for nodeJS server you can set them like this:
`res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");`

Comment: @maurycy Console (Chrome) gives 'DELETE [url] 403 Forbidden'. 
Network tab shows (in red) a status of 403. I'm not experienced in how to use these developer tools. I have made other apps and posted them in a similar way to this server with no single issue.

Comment: @Rafael Zeffa: Het app is communicating with the database via a small PHP Restful Api (https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/02/simple-php-rest-api-script-mysql/)

Comment: @BotanMan: I don't know what CORS is. So I'm not using it.
Localhost works fine so I think my code is right. The server responds good with get and post, no delete or put.

Comment: In any case when you app is hosted on one domain but the api is hosted on another each request will be cross-origin. 
In any way, it also possible that there are ACL (Account Control List) so your user don't have enough permission to do DELETE or PUT cause there requests are potentially dangerous.

Comment: @BotanMan: The api is hosted on the same domain: the api is in the same folder where the app is.
There is no ACL.

Comment: Have you looked in fiddler to see exactly what is being sent around? If so, do you see preflight requests?

Answer (score 0):

You should whitelist the domains you allow request from on your (I think) php server ?

This is done like this :

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

This way you can also select the allowed methods, like GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS and more..

Comment: @ Shoeb: Yes, you're right, I'm pulling the data from a database via an api.php
I've placed those headers 

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, PUT, GET, POST");

in the top of this api.php, but no result. It keeps saying error 403 with put or delete operations.

Comment: I've read something about CSRF or XSRF (http://angularjs-best-practices.blogspot.nl/2013/07/angularjs-and-xsrfcsrf-cross-site.html) Could it be this error has something to do with it?

Comment: I get just this message from the console: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)'

Comment: I still didn't find a solution. So I made a workaround by using $http.post